# spark dynamic allocation executors failing

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use dynamic allocation in standalone mode in spark to allow multiple users to run jobs at the same time. I have enabled dynamic allocation and shuffle service in the spark-defaults.conf file:

```
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 0
```

When I try to run two pyspark shells concurrently, the executors fail and I get an error:

```
 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 7 on XXXX: 
 Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding 
 thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening or suggestions to better use dynamic allocation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark dynamic allocation is for reducing or increasing the number of executors when needed, defined by max and min number of executors.It doesn't has to do with allowing multiple users. In some way it is helpful when spark shell is holding resources and not using it, it will free those containers. 
Please paste full error log, this might be due to you have requested more executors than you have defined in spark-defaults.conf